# Why the frobenius $\mathbb F_p^{alg}\longrightarrow \mathbb F_p^{alg}$ s.t. $x\longmapsto x^p$ is surjective?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

Consider the frobenius $\mathbb F_p^{alg}\longrightarrow \mathbb F_p^{alg}$ defined by $x\longmapsto x^p$.

1) Why is it surjective ? I recall that $\mathbb F_p^{alg}$ is an algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_p=\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.

2) Can I then conclude that $x\longmapsto x^{p^n}$ is surjective ? I would say yes since if $\sigma :x\longmapsto x^p$, then $x\longmapsto x^{p^n}$ is in fact $\sigma ^n$ and thus it's the composition of $n$ surjection, and thus it's it self surjective.

Comment: Just write up what it would mean for an element to be in the preimage of something, and remember the definition of being algebraically closed.

Comment: It mean that $x^{p^n}-x=0$. I know that all solution is in $\mathbb F_p^{alg}$ (since it's algebrically closed). But why all element of $\mathbb F_p^{alg}$ would be a root of $x^{p^n}-x$ ? It's my problem.

Comment: No, that is not what it means. $x$ is the preimage of $y$ if $x^p = y$.

Comment: Si if $y\in \mathbb F_p^{alg}$, how can I show that there is an $x$ s.t. $y=x^{p}$ ? It's not easy, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, it really is easy, because this is the same as there being a zero of the polynomial $z^p - y$.

Comment: So $z=\sqrt[p]y$ ? But how can I prove that it's in $\mathbb F_p^{alg}$ ?

Comment: By recalling what it means to be algebraically closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an algebraic closed field every non-constant polynomial has a root.

For a fixed $y$ a root $r$ of $X^p-y$ will satisfy $r^p=y$.